# Searching for values in arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop, search

I have an array in C# that generates random array of length 5. I have already declared this way

```
int[] array = new int[5]
```

I'm supposed to search for an array, an input dialog box opens, and I type in any value. It is supposed to give me an output if the number is found or else display not found and keep on going till I input the correct number.

I have this code something like this, it gives me some values not the kind i need. How can i implement such that it satisfies my condition? Thanks in advance.

```
    private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //use InputBox dialog to input a value.
        //Search for the value in the array.
        //If found, display "Found!", otherwise
        //display "Not found!" when there is no match.

        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            InputBox inputDlg = new InputBox("Search for array value " + (i + 1));
            if (inputDlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                if (array[i] == Array.IndexOf(array, 5))
                {
                    array[i] = Convert.ToInt32(inputDlg.Input);
                }
                tbxOutput.AppendText("Value found: " + array[i] + Environment.NewLine);
            }

            else
            {
                tbxOutput.AppendText("Value not found" + Environment.NewLine);
            }
        }
```

Comment: is `Convert.ToInt32(inputDlg.Input)` returning you the value you need to look for in the array?

Comment: Yes, it returns the array values, but i have not typed anything in the input, just clicked ok all the way..the statement above works.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you have 1 array with 5 values in it, and you want to check if it contains a given value. Is that correct? 
If yes you have to loop through your array and flag a boolean to `true` if you find it:

```
private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    // loop until you call break
    while(true) {

        // ask for a value
        InputBox inputDlg = new InputBox("Search for array value " + (i + 1));

        try {
            int value = Convert.ToInt32(inputDlg.Input);

            // Check if value is in the array and display the appropriate message
            if(isInArray(array, value)) {
                tbxOutput.AppendText("Value found: " + value + Environment.NewLine);
                // break to exit from the while loop
                break;
            } else {
                tbxOutput.AppendText("Value not found" + Environment.NewLine);
            } 

        } catch (OverflowException) {
            tbxOutput.AppendText("OverflowException parsing input to int" + Environment.NewLine);
        } catch (FormatException) {
            tbxOutput.AppendText("FormatException parsing input to int" + Environment.NewLine);
        }   

    }
}
```

The `isInArray` method:

```
// this method returns true if the given value is in the array
private static boolean isInArray(int[] array, int valueToFind) {
    boolean found = false;
    int currentValue;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++) {
        currentValue = array[i];
        if(currentValue == valueToFind) {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return found;
}
```

Comment: Yes. But before that a dialog box opens asking the user to type a number. If ok, it will display found, else keep on looping till a correct number is found. Im using windows forms apps instead of windows console. (inputDlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)

Comment: @Ralph I edited my answer to include the loop and the dialog boxes

Comment: There is a `for` loop in `isInArray`. For the other loop you can't use a `for` loop, unless you want to have a limited number of tries. `while` is the only way to keep asking until a correct value is entered.

Comment: @Ralph I edited my answer, you now have that exact line in the isInArray method

Comment: @Ralph what language are you using? is it Java or C# or something else?

Comment: C#. Thanks it makes more sense now but this line seems to be giving an exception, should an exception handler be added? int value = Convert.ToInt32(inputDlg.Input);

Comment: @Ralph I added a try/catch, it will probably work. Please upvote and accept my answer if it helped you.